# Past Simple vs. Past Continuous

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

I'd appreciate your opinion on this grammar task item to elicit the correct use of the past simple/continuous.

> Last Halloween little Joe went missing. We ... (run) around the block
> looking for him while he ... (hide) in the boot of our car. We only
> ... (discover) him when he ... (get) bored and ... (cry) for help.

I'm wondering, if the use of the past continuous (was running, was hiding) is mandatory in this case. To me, last Halloween is not a short period, which usually seems to go along with that grammatical form, suggesting the use of the past simple. Running around the block and hiding in the car, however, are parallel actions. Is this the reason, the Past Continuous may be more appropriate here?

Thank you for sharing your thoughts,

the pretzel

Answer (score -1):

No, the continuous form is not mandatory. All the blanks in your practice question can be filled with the simple past.

Why?

When you use the conjunction "while" in a time clause, it means the event is continuous, regardless of the verb in that clause, so the meaning is the same whether you use simple past or past continuous.